# Acces outer scope variable from load callback function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to acces a variable inside load callback function. I only have acces to this, and event parameters. Is it possible to set a new property to Highcharts object to acces it via `this`?

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/q82L6jzs/5/) is what I'm trying to do:

```js
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        myBoolean ? console.log("HERE") : console.log("THERE");
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Hi @Bernardo Marques, In your example you have an access to the `myBoolean` variable. What do exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Interesting, In my case I have a function call for the highcharts constructor on other file, I think that´s why I don't have acces to it on that other file. Maybe I need to initialize a new variable inside the callback that gets this outer value. This way when highcharts generates the object to initialize it it will load this callback and have the boolean.

Comment: I have handled it using the boolean outside of callback, generating different callbacks depending on the boolean, but I'll try this new approach and update here.